# Disable ribbonbuttons

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon

Im currently develpoing a ribbon using the Ribbon Framework for WPF.

I have seen that in office there are "disabled buttons" that will be "activated" once a condition is satisfied.

Does anyone have an idea how to implent such feature?

Also, notice the "textbox" to the left of the redbox marking the "Position" ribbonbutton, is there anyway to extend the ribbon textbox to get those "Arrow up and Arrow down" Buttons to increase a number "+1" and "-1"

[image]

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

When you bind an [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.ICommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance to the `RibbonButton.Command` property, then you can disable and enable the button by adding a `bool` condition into the [`ICommand.CanExecute` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When the condition returns true, the `RibbonButton` will be enabled and when it returns false, it will be disabled.

In XAML:

```
<Ribbon:RibbonButton Command="{Binding Activate, Mode=OneWay}" Label="Activate" ... />
```

In code (using a form of `RelayCommand`):

```
public ICommand Activate
{
    get { return new ActionCommand(action => ActivateCommand(), 
canExecute => CanActivate()); } // output of CanActivate will enable/disable button
}
```